# What is the advantage of Justice League Flash suit over the TV series suit?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, dc-extended-universe, the-flash-2014, justice-league-2017

In the ***Crisis on Infinite Earths*** of CW Arrowverse, the DCEU *Flash* meets the *Flash* of Arrowverse and they have fun banter. They discuss about their respective costumes. I want to know, what are the advantages of the DCEU Flash suit over the Arrowverse Flash suit. Include the Arrowverse Flash suit used in the Season 6 of **The Flash** with all its modifications. I want to know about the material used and the benefits of that material and also the gadgets involved in the suit.

Comment: The Arrowverse Flash suit is way more sexier.

Comment: DCEU Flash suit = Power Rangers (2017)
.
.
Arrowverse Flash suit = Original Power Rangers

Comment: The DCEU Flash suit has a mighty and mysterious power that [delays filming of Flash solo adventures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Extended_Universe#The_Flash_(2022)). No-one yet knows the true extent of its might!

Comment: The DCEU Flash suit allows the wearer to look good no matter how bad the film around him is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The movie suit:

> Bruce: Silica-based quartz and fabric. Abrasion resistant. Heat resistant.
>
> Barry: Uh, yeah, I do competitive ice dancing.
>
> Bruce: It's what they use on the space shuttle to prevent it from burning up on reentry.
>
> Barry: I do... very competitive ice dancing.
>
> -*Justice League, 2017*

The TV suit is [repurposed from a prototype fire-fighter's suit.](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/The_Flash_suits) It's made of reinforced tri-polymer (??).

So while the movie suit could theoretically withstand re-entry, while TV Barry would potentially burn up, the TV suit currently has many capabilities that the movie suit does not, including (the source is the above link):

- A variant which can fit into a ring
- A voice altering device
- A floatation device
- The ability to remotely monitor the wearer's vitals
- The ability to self repair

Also, it used to have a defibrillator, but apparently that's broken.